# Scala — Conditional replace column value of a data frame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

DF1 is what I have now, and I want make DF1 looks like DF2.

Desired Output:

```
 DF1                                DF2
+---------+-------------------+          +---------+------------------------------+
|   ID    | Category          |          |   ID    | Category                     |
+---------+-------------------+          +---------+------------------------------+  
|  31898  |   Transfer        |          |  31898  |  Transfer (e-Transfer)       |  
|  31898  |  e-Transfer       |  =====>  |  32614  |  Transfer (e-Transfer + IMT) |
|  32614  |   Transfer        |  =====>  |  33987  |   Transfer (IMT)             |
|  32614  |  e-Transfer + IMT |          +---------+------------------------------+      
|  33987  |   Transfer        |  
|  33987  |    IMT            |  
+---------+-------------------+
```

Code:

```
val df = DF1.groupBy("ID").agg(collect_set("Category").as("CategorySet"))
val DF2 = df.withColumn("Category", $"CategorySet"(0) ($"CategorySet"(1)))
```

How should I solve this? And if there is any other better ways to do the same thing, I am open to it. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way using UDF:

```
val flatten = udf((xs: Seq[String]) => xs.mkString(" + "))

df.groupBy("ID").agg(flatten(collect_set("Category")).as("CategorySet")).show(false)

+-----+---------------------------+
|ID   |CategorySet                |
+-----+---------------------------+
|33987|Transfer                   |
|32614|Transfer + e-Transfer + IMT|
|34193|e-Transfer                 |
|31898|Transfer + e-Transfer      |
+-----+---------------------------+
```

Another way is to just use `concat_ws`:

```
df.groupBy("ID").agg(concat_ws(" + ",collect_set("Category")).as("CategorySet")).show(false)

+-----+---------------------------+
|ID   |CategorySet                |
+-----+---------------------------+
|33987|Transfer                   |
|32614|Transfer + e-Transfer + IMT|
|34193|e-Transfer                 |
|31898|Transfer + e-Transfer      |
+-----+---------------------------+
```